# Difference and usage between WebForms' DynamicHyperLink and HyperLink

Tags: asp.net

What is the difference between these two server controls?  When would I use one over the other?

Comment: Maybe if you explained what you were trying to do someone could suggest which control would be the most appropriate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[DynamicHyperLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.dynamicdata.dynamichyperlink%28VS.100%29.aspx) is used for dynamic data table actions (e.g. Edit, Insert) whereas [HyperLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) simply represents a standard link to another page which you can manipulate server side.

Comment: well i saw many times that hyperlink is used for edit field in gridview like <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="ID" 
                    DataNavigateUrlFormatString="userDetail.aspx?ID={0}" />

Comment: [HyperLinkField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield.aspx) is a column type for data bound controls such as GridView.  It will display a link for each record in the data bound control.  However DynamicHyperLink would have to be declared inside an ItemTemplate in a GridView as it does not inherit from DataControlField.